# Meaning of (%eax) in AT&T syntax?

Tags: assembly, x86, addressing-mode

You'll have to excuse me, I'm brand new to x86 assembly, and assembly in general.

So my question is, I have something like:

```
addl %edx,(%eax)
```

%eax is a register which holds a pointer to some integer. Let's call it xp

Does this mean that it's saying: `*xp = *xp + %edx`? (`%edx` is an integer)

I'm just confused where addl will store the result. If `%eax` is a pointer to an int, then `(%eax)` should be the actual value of that int. So would `addl` store the result of `%edx+(%eax)` in `*xp`? I would really love for someone to explain this to me!

I really appreciate any help!

Answer (score 51, accepted):

Yes, this instruction is doing exactly what you think it's doing.

Most x86 arithmetic instructions take two operands: a source and a destination. In AT&T syntax (used here), the destination is always the right operand. So with an instruction like:

```
addl %edx, %eax
```

the values in `edx` and `eax` are added together and the result is stored in `eax`. However, in your example, `(%eax)` is a memory operand; that's what parentheses mean in AT&T syntax (like square-brackets in NASM syntax).

This means that `eax` is treated as a pointer, so the right operand is taken from the address pointed to by `eax`, and the result is stored to the same address.

Comment: `(%eax)` is "register indirect", if you want to [name different addressing modes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46257018/do-terms-like-direct-indirect-addressing-mode-actual-exists-in-the-intel-x86-man) at all.  "Memory indirect" addressing is when the CPU loads an address from memory and then dereferences *that* (x86 doesn't support memory-indirect addressing).  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Addressing_mode#Memory_indirect