# Memory indirect addressing movl - assembly

Tags: c, assembly, addressing-mode

I'm trying to understand how exactly memory indirect addressing works in assembly language with AT&T syntax.

```
movl (%eax), %ebx

movl %eax, (%ebx)
```

Here is a similar question that explains about [memory indirect addressing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1619131/addl-instruction-x86)

This is what I've understood:

In the first case, you `load` the data pointed to by the register `%eax`  and store it in `%ebx`.

In the second case, you `store` the data in the register `%eax` to the address space pointed to by the register `%ebx`. Am I correct?

Comment: you are correct. In C it would be `ebx = *eax` and `*ebx = eax`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Basically the syntax is

```
movl source, destination
```

So `movl (%eax), %ebx` is indeed copy the value at address pointed to by %eax into %ebx. And `movl %eax, (%ebx)` is copy the value inside register %eax into the address pointed to by %ebx.

So indeed your understanding is correct.

Comment: Thanks!. Can look at the next part of the code with a better frame of mind now!