# Does `mov edx, Len` for printing to stdout store the value or the address of "Len" into the register?

Tags: assembly, x86, nasm, cpu-registers

I am new to assembly programming (x86 32bit architecture) and have a question about the following piece of code:

```
SECTION .data

Msg: db "Hello", 10
Len: equ $-Msg

SECTION .text

global _start

_start:
    ; Printing Msg to stdout
    mov eax, 4
    mov ebx, 1
    mov ecx, Msg  ; Passing the ADDRESS to the beginning of what's stored in Msg
    mov edx, Len  ; Are we passing the address of Len, or the value of Len?
    int 80H

    ; Terminating
    mov eax, 1
    mov ebx, 0
    int 80H
```

I was told that `mov ecx, Msg` instruction moves the address of where the `Msg` is stored into the `ecx` register.

**What about the next instruction** `mov edx, Len`?

- If we move the `Len` value to the `edx` register, then shouldn't the instruction be written differently, like `mov edx, [Len]`?
- If we move the address of `Len` then why is the system call to print the message so complicated? Why do you need a register to contain an address to the length of the message rather than the actual length value?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`Len` doesn't have an address.  A label defined with `equ` simply makes the name `Len` a convenient way to refer to a particular numerical value, which in this case is computed by the assembler and happens to be 6.  It doesn't allocate any space in memory.  And `mov edx, Len` is an immediate load that puts that numerical value 6 in the `edx` register.

In some sense, `Msg` is *also* a convenient way to refer to a particular numerical value - but here that numerical value happens to be the address of a certain location in memory that contains the bytes "Hello".  So `mov ecx, Msg` is also an immediate load that puts that numerical value into `ecx`.

If you like, you can think of `Msg: db "Hello", 10` as a shorthand for

```
Msg: equ $
    db "Hello", 10
```

It sets the label `Msg` equal to the assembler's current address, then assembles some bytes starting at the current address.

(Note that this answer is specific to nasm.  Other Intel-syntax assemblers are generally similar; but for instance, in AT&T syntax, the instruction `movl Len, %edx` is a move from memory, the equivalent of Intel's `mov edx, [Len]`; it would attempt to fetch four bytes from address 6, which would crash.  In that syntax you would instead write `movl $Len, %edx`.)

Comment: terminology: A `[disp32]` addressing mode is normally called "direct" (or absolute), because the address is literally there in the instruction encoding.  Indirect would be `[reg]`.  But yes, it's a load from memory instead of a mov-immediate.  x86 doesn't give specific names to different subsets of its full addressing-mode capability (`[base + idx*scale + disp0/8/32]`), but some people like to name things.  [Do terms like direct/indirect addressing mode actual exists in the Intel x86 manuals](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46257018)

Comment: " in AT&T syntax, the instruction `mov Len, %edx` is" -- Usually you'd come across `movl` as the instruction with AT&T syntax.

Comment: @ecm: Good point, though with gas it is optional in that example because the operand size can be deduced from the register name.  I changed it anyway.

Comment: @Nate Eldredge: You forgot one of the instructions in your text.